# WiFi on laptop regularly isn't recognized on boot

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

Laptop model is Asus K53TA. It's ~7 year old.

The problem is that WiFi will randomly not be recognized on boot, but is recognized after few reboots (up to 10 sometimes). When it's not recognized, system just doesn't see it in Device Manager on Windows (but situation is same on Linux, checked with `lspci | grep -i wireless`). If it is recognized, however, it works stable without any issues.

Ethernet is always working.

WiFi-LED on laptop shows that WiFi is on (and it reacts to `Fn+[WiFi button]`).

Situation is same on Windows 8, Windows 10, Debian Jessie, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04 (yes, I have this problem for quite some time now). I don't remember when it started exactly.

How can I check whether this is software problem (and if it is, then how to fix it) or is it maybe due to some hardware damage?

Comment: I have sometimes had a related problem when switching between Linux and Windows. I assumed that the drivers on one OS left the hardware in a state that the drivers on the other OS couldn't handle. What always worked was to remove power and battery for 10 seconds - the WiFi always worked on the next boot. It might be worth trying in your case.

Comment: This happens even when I use one system (Windows) for months exclusively. I have GRUB, if that matters.

Comment: It still might be worth trying. I boot Ubuntu through `grub`, but I need to go to the UEFI boot menu to boot Windows, though there is a `grub` entry `Windows Boot Manager` to transfer to this.